# Android emulator root access app

Tags: android, emulation, root

I am having trouble copying files to the virtual sdcard on the android emulator. I am creating an app that copies the data/data/package folder to the sdcard. This works fine when the app copies its own package but it won't do it for other apps. I have looked into other topics, but I can't seem to give my app super user status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android Developers, [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html):

> A central design point of the Android security architecture is that no
>   application, by default, has permission to perform any operations that
>   would adversely impact other applications, the operating system, or
>   the user. This includes reading or writing the user's private data
>   (such as contacts or e-mails), reading or writing another
>   application's files, performing network access, keeping the device
>   awake, etc.

Moreover,

> Because Android sandboxes applications from each other, applications
>   must explicitly share resources and data. They do this by declaring
>   the permissions they need for additional capabilities not provided by
>   the basic sandbox.

So, this answers your question about why you cannot write data from other applications. In order to do what you want, share data between applications, you need to sign the applications with the same signature and request the same `sharedUserId`, as it is shown in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot give your app super user status. the only way a phone can access the data folders is by using a rooted phone. Android is designed so that an app cannot modify other apps without permission. It's a security feature.

Comment: I know that which is why I want to know how to root the emulator.

Comment: you don't need to, just use DDMS